# Listing databases on a remote OrientDB server

Tags: java, database, orientdb

is there a way to connect to a remote OrientDB server and list the available databases? What I would like to have is "list databases" using Java. (Something like here using the command line: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Run-the-console.html - Connecting to server instance)
What would be the minimum code to archive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
OServerAdmin admin = new OServerAdmin("remote:localhost");
admin.connect("root", "root");
admin.listDatabases();
```

OServerAdmin is the class to admin a remote server instance of OrientDB.
Create an instance with URL , connect with root credential that you can find in orientdb-server-config.xml in your ODB installation, and then call the listDatabases() API to get the databases list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the **root** password is root, something like this:

```
OServerAdmin server = new OServerAdmin("remote:localhost").connect("root", "root");
Set<String> dbsNames = server.listDatabases().keySet();
```